# How to maintain styles across browsers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cross-browser

I've got a `ul`, in Chrome it maintains its size relative to its container and scales, in IE it doesnt scale instead acting like theres no css.

The second photo is how it looks at full screen, the first photo is how it looks after scaling however when scaling in IE it continues to look like the second photo.
I thought this was because of Flexbox but as you can see every prefix I can think of has been applied.

I've can a number of compatibility checks and it looked like the issue was the use of rem but changing this to % or pixel doesn't change a thing.
Every other section of the sites is compatible across all browsers and scales fine even on mobile devices.
I haven't applied a style to this that isn't used in any of the other sections so this literally makes no sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
#skills {
  height: 40rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(27, 28, 28, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#lang {
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#bar {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
  -moz-box-align: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lang">
  <ul id="bar">
    <li class="bars"><span class="bartxt">HTML 5</span></li>
    <li class="bars"><span class="bartxt">CSS 3</span></li>
    <li class="bars"><span class="bartxt">Git</span></li>
    <li class="bars"><span class="bartxt">Responsive design</span></li>
    <li class="bars"><span class="bartxt">Unicycling</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Correct]
[image: Incorrect]

Comment: IE9 and below don't support `flex` at all, not even with prefixes, but I would question whether it's worth bothering to support a browser that is now 7 *years* out of date...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said this is the same in Edge and Opera. Not to sure on the use of Opera but I do know Edge is MS flagship browser now so I'm thinking I should make it compatible.

Comment: The code you've posted seems incomplete. There's also a `#skills` rule but no corresponding element. If you're having problems with Opera, then you should check what version you're using, because it usually renders the same as Chrome (since they're both Chromium-based).